# jQuery json Ajax call no longer works after first time (including form submit, setTimeout)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a rather long running submit, so I implemented a modal dialog with a progress bar to show the progress. The *first time* I submit the form everything works fine. The progress bar is being updated (I use setTimeout in the success handler to check the progress every 500 ms) and shown in the modal dialog. The contents of the div below it are also updated, and when everything is done the form submits. That's where it gets tricky...

After the first time I submitted the form, it is *impossible* to get the progress bar to update again other than to reset my IIS Express. The modal dialog is showm, I can see the first json request being fired but it just waits and aborts as soon as the submit is through. I tried adding a timeout to the $.ajax call, adding headers to not have the result of the json call cached, I tried clearing the timeouts but all to no avail.

I think the problem has something to do with setTimeout being aborted by the form submit (and the redirect done after the form was submitted). Somehow I can't seem to find the real culprit.

```
function DoSomething() {
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        url: "/Controller/Action",
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: 400,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                if ($('progress').prop('max') !== data.total) {
                    $('progress').attr({ max: data.total });
                }
                $('progress').attr({ value: data.current });
                $('#progressText').html(data.current + ' / ' + data.total);
            }
            setTimeout(DoSomething, 500);
        }
    });
}
```

And in the view where I'm using this...

```
$("form").submit(function () {
    $('#thisIsMyModal').modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false
    });
    DoSomething();
});
```

Comment: Are you cache the response from your controller at all? Also can you post the response from each call Ajax call?

Comment: I added the OutputCache attribute with duration = 0 and NoStore to the controller action. I also added a cache-control header no-cache to no avail.

Comment: Here are some responses: {"current":0,"total":951}, {"current":49,"total":951}, {"current":109,"total":951}

Response headers: Key Value
Response HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control private
Content-Type application/json; charset=utf-8
Server Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version 4.0
X-AspNet-Version 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles =?UTF-8?B?RDpcRGV2ZWxvcG1lbnRccmlja3ZkYm9zY2hcUm9lZmVsXFJvZWZlbC5XZWIuTXZjXEJlaGVlclxHZXRTZXNzaW9uc0NsYXNzaWZpZWQ=?=
X-Powered-By ASP.NET
Date Thu, 06 Jun 2013 18:34:20 GMT
Content-Length 26

Answer (score 1):

To your ajax request add a `cache: false`. I had the same problem in my MVC application until setting that to false. You won't find good documentation on it though, it was something I dug up on a obscure website a while back.

EDIT:  I stand corrected, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/